# mips32 break instruction executed

Tags: assembly, break, mips32

I am getting this weird exception every time I run my program: "line 168: Runtime exception at 0x00400278: break instruction executed; no code given."
line 168 is rem $s3,$s4,$t0 under findKey label.
I have probably messed up something while I was trying to solve other issues with my code. If anyone could tell me what this exception means and what would be the best way to fix it I'd highly appreciate it.

Here is the part of my code i believe has the issue:

```
findKey:
    rem $s3,$s4,$t0
    jal loop
    jr $ra
loop:
    bge $t4,$t0,end1 #if counter = 10 exit loop
    j l1         #Else go to L1

l1:     
    beqz $t3,l2 #if found = 0 continue searching (go to L2)
    j end1      #else go to end1

l2:     
    addi $t4,$t4,1
    addi $t5,$t5,4
    #move $t7,$s7
    lw $t7,($t5)    # hash[position]
    beq $t7,$s4,l3
    j else

l3:     
    li $t3,1
    j end1
else:   
    addi $s3,$s3,1
    rem $s3,$s3,$t0
    j loop

end1:   
    beq $t3,1,return1
    #return
    j return2
return1:
    move $s2,$s3    #Print result
    jr $ra

return2:
    sw $s2,minus
    jr $ra
```

Comment: I suspect that you have delayed branching enabled in the simulator you're using. The way that PCSpim translates the `rem` pseudo-instruction is incompatible with delayed branching. I haven't checked if it's the same with QtSpim/Mars, but it might be. Either disable delayed branching in the simulator's settings, or write your own implementation of `rem` using the `div` instruction.

Comment: thank you for replying, i am using Mars (cause its more user friendly than any other simulator i found) and QtSpim cause that's the one they want us to use in University. The setting "delayed branching" is disabled in both, i am guessing my issue has to do with jal / jr $ra

Comment: Well, every `jal` modifies `$ra`. So if you have nested `jal`s you need to save `$ra` somwhere (e.g. on the stack) so that you can restore it later.

Comment: i think i got it thanks!